# Programmatically downloading a large number of <insert file type here>

Tags: search, scripting, download

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to download a large number of files of one arbitrary type, e.g., downloading 10,000 XML files. In the past, I've used Bing's API. It's free and offers unlimited queries. However, it doesn't index as many types of files as Google does. Google indexes XML files, CSV files, and KML files. (These can all be found by doing searches like "filetype:XML".) As far as I know, Bing doesn't index these in a way that's easily searchable. Is there another API that has these capabilities?

Comment: Do you just mean randomly downloading a bunch of files?

Comment: Yes, but of one specific type. An example would be downloading 15,000 KML files.

Comment: I have no idea why you'd want to do that, but it's certainly an interesting idea.

Comment: Well, your title says programmatically. Why not build a program to parse the output of the google query, turn that into a bunch of URLS that you put into a file and call something like `curl -f fileList`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `wget`? You can give `wget` a URL (for example, a google search result) and tell it to follow all the links on that page and download them (I bet you could also give it a filter).

Just tried it and got an `ERROR 403: Forbidden.` Apparently Google blocks requests from Wget. You'll have to provide a different user agent. Quick search provided this example:

http://www.mail-archive.com/wget@sunsite.dk/msg06564.html

Then it worked with the example given.